# Updating a Variable through a Mixin

Tags: css, less

So lets say I set the background of 10 elements on the page to @base, then a user lands on the "Foo" page which has the class on the body of the page.

How does one update the @base via a css declaration? I understand that variables are local to a function (or css declaration) but there must be a method to do this! (would make styling alternative pages so easy!)

```
@base: #00000;

body.foo{
 @base = #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### LESS is a Preprocessor so...

...it all has to be precompiled into CSS ahead of time. That means all possible class combinations need to be made into valid CSS ahead of time. If you wanted something like this, you would need to do something like the following in your LESS:

**LESS**

```css
@base: #000000;

.setColorOptions(@className: ~'', @base: @base) {
  @classDot: escape(`('@{className}' == '' ? '' : '.')`);
  @class: escape(@className);
  body@{classDot}@{class} {
     someElement {color: @base;}
     .someClass {color: @base;}
    // etc.
  }
}
.setColorOptions();
.setColorOptions(foo, #fff);
.setColorOptions(bar, #ccc);
```

**CSS Output**

```css
body someElement {
  color: #000000;
}
body .someClass {
  color: #000000;
}
body.foo someElement {
  color: #ffffff;
}
body.foo .someClass {
  color: #ffffff;
}
body.bar someElement {
  color: #cccccc;
}
body.bar .someClass {
  color: #cccccc;
}
```

**Obviously** if there were many elements and a lot of color dependent things going on, this could get big fast. Imagine 100 elements under `body` with three color variations as above, and you have 300+ lines of CSS, 200+ (two-thirds) of which do not apply to any one page. And this doesn't account for other changes, like background colors, etc. In such a case, it is best to set up different LESS files that import a different set of values for `@base` and build different style sheets to be loaded on the pages that need it. However, if you are just doing a small subset of color changes to a page, this could be a valid way to go.

Comment: +1 always serving such excellent solutions and advice! Then I feel that just giving a vote isn't enough ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that.

`LESS` has no way to know whether the selector `body.foo` will apply at compile time.